# Obter conteudo completo de um XML sem remover as tags

Tags: php, xml

Preciso obter o conteúdo completo de um arquivo XML para inseri-lo no banco de dados. Já tentei **fopen** mas ele retira as tags, e com **simplexml_load_file** retorna array.

```
$ponteiro = fopen ($arquivo,"r");
while (!feof ($ponteiro)) {
$linha = fgets($ponteiro);
echo $linha."<br>";
}
fclose ($ponteiro);
```

Assim ele retorna somente o conteudo em texto sem as tags.
Exemplo de parte do XML completo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe versao="3.10" Id="NFe3516............">
<ide>
<cUF>35</cUF>
<cNF>00001623</cNF>
<natOp>VENDA DE MERCADORIA</natOp>
<indPag>1</indPag>
<mod>55</mod>
<serie>1</serie>
<nNF>1023</nNF>
<dhEmi>2016-09-02T19:57:00-03:00</dhEmi>
<dhSaiEnt>2016-09-05T19:57:00-03:00</dhSaiEnt>
<tpNF>1</tpNF>
<idDest>1</idDest>
<cMunFG>3530607</cMunFG>
```

Preciso ler um arquivo XML de uma pasta e salvar seu conteudo no MYSQL

Comment: [RESOLVIDO] Obrigado @Bacco inseri no banco de dados o retorno e gravou corretamente, se imprimir no browser ele retira as tags mesmo.

Comment: No seu caso, essa solução aqui é mais prática, pra ler tudo de uma vez só: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O conteudo está retornando perfeito com as tags, é normal não conseguir vê-las na tela, pois o navegador tenta interpretar como HTML.

Basta uma pequena correção, se quer ver a saída pelo navegador:

```
$ponteiro = fopen( $arquivo, 'r' );
while ( !feof ($ponteiro) ) {
   $linha = fgets( $ponteiro );
   echo htmlentities( $linha )."<br>\n";
}
fclose ($ponteiro);
```

Notar que não mudamos nada na leitura, apenas acrescentamos um `htmlentities()` no `echo`, para que as tags sejam "escapadas" corretamente para exibição em HTML.

Para guardar em uma variável ou DB, não precisa do `htmlentities`, use os dados da forma que são lidos.

### Alternativa

Se quiser ler o arquivo numa etapa só:

```
$xml = file_get_contents( $arquivo );
echo nl2br( htmlentities( $xml ) );
```

Esta opção é boa quando o arquivo não é tão grande e pode ser lido na memória e processado em uma única etapa, o que costuma ser o caso de XMLs.

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php

O `nl2br` serve para transformar quebras de linha em tags `<br>`, para facilitar a leitura